# Company mode suggestions end up all over the screen

Tags: company-mode

When I am programming I utilize `company-mode` heavily to save me time typing. There's a problem however. Let's say I have a bunch of stuff with a similar prefix:

```
createThingX
createThingY
createThingZ
createThing1
createThing2
createThing3
```

`company-mode` will suggest these things properly. However, after the fifth or sixth suggestion in the list it appears to create a second column of suggestions. This wouldn't be a problem except the second column of suggestions is usually nearly off the screen.

Is there a way to tell `company` how many suggestions to give per column?